# How to delete a command in gitbash which I already typed and when the cursor went to the next line

Tags: terminal, git-bash

How can I delete a command which I already executed but I made some mistake due to negligence is there any way to delete my previous command line in git bash terminal

Comment: What was the command?

Comment: I forgot to put quotations after writing a command but now I came to the new line as I pressed enter. How to go to previous line

Comment: It really depends on what the command does. You can delete a command from you history, but it won't nullify its effects. If the command modifies the file system in a bad way it may be hard to roll back unfortunately. What did the command do?

Comment: git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"

Comment: I think it is used to make sublime useful for making commit messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press `Ctrl` + `C` to cancel a command.

Comment: No, Actually the problem is I didnot even run the command properly , I pressed enter and went to the next line without putting quotations after the command line

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Changed my answer :)